# The origin of and the difference between primogenitor, primogeniture and progenitor

Tags: meaning, word-usage, etymology, differences

In *Etymonline*, the etymology of *[primogenitor](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=primogenitor)* (and [*primogeniture*](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=primogeniture)) is very similar to [*progenitor*](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=progenitor). The word's meaning: Ancestor or forefather.


However, nowhere do I find the **reason** of the split from the word *progenitor*. Why does such word exist? When and where (near the 1650s) did it first appear? What is the correlation to the primogeniture succession law?

---

In a related manner, what is the difference to progenitor? When would one use one or the other?

---

Edit: Is the assertion that progenitor means the ancestor of a person, while primogenitor means the initial common ancestor of a people, correct?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using it at all - it's a _very_ obscure word!

Comment: Exactly. And you never will find the link to any other word, because the information is buried in the past motions of millions of tongues now dead. Historical linguistics is like doing archaeology on ghosts instead of bones.

Comment: So could I consider Primogenitor, basically an obsolete word? How pitiful..

Comment: Well, the Merriam-Webster dictionary does recognise 'primogenitor'; under its 'History and Etymology' it says
'borrowed from New Latin prīmogenitor (Medieval Latin, "eldest son"), from prīmo- (in Late Latin prīmogenitus "firstborn," prīmogenitūra "condition of being the firstborn") + Latin genitor "father, parent, originator" — more at PRIMOGENITURE, PROGENITOR'

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the Cambridge English Dictionary online, it does not recognise the word *primogenitor*.  There is a word *Primogeniture*.  Primogeniture is the monarchical system of replacing one deceased monarch with their 'first born' child.

Merriam Webster does cite the word in the question, with a usage in 1643, celebrating the bicentenary of the founding fathers:

> the family held a huge reunion to mark the 200th anniviersary of their primogenitors' arrival in America.

I am afraid that this usage looks like a malapropism or perhaps misspelling for the word *progeniture*. MW's definition confirms that diagnosis.

> ANCESTOR, FOREFATHER

The word *progenitor* means precisely that.  The definition of primogeniture in Cambridge is

> the custom by which all of a family's property goes to the oldest son when the father dies.

Comment: *Primogenitor* is in the OED meaning "A person from whom another is originally descended; the earliest ancestor, esp. of a people; a forefather, a progenitor. Also in extended use." the etymology is from post classical Latin.